# Python lxml custom parser isn't working with lxml.etree.parse(...) function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

In a python 3.5 project I have to read in some xml files and I decided to use the lxml library. Since I'm reading in files the most efficient way to do this according to the documentation is by reading using the lxml.etree.parse(...) function.

The problem I'm having is that this function seems to always use the default parser even though I'm passing a custom one. The lxml.etree.fromstring(...) function does work properly.

This code shows the problem I'm having. parse() gives the same output if I give it a file path.

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree

class honk(etree.ElementBase):
    pass

parser_lookup = etree.ElementDefaultClassLookup(element=honk)
parser = etree.XMLParser()
parser.set_element_class_lookup(parser_lookup)

elem1 = etree.parse(StringIO("<test/>"), parser)
elem2 = etree.fromstring("<test/>", parser)

print(isinstance(elem1, honk), type(elem1))
print(isinstance(elem2, honk), type(elem2))
```

Output

```
False <class 'lxml.etree._ElementTree'>
True <class '__main__.honk'>
```

I have no idea what causing it or how to solve it. I can work around it, but such a bug in the library seems strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `parse()` and `fromstring()` returns different types. Quoted from [The `lxml.etree` Tutorial > The `parse()` function](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) :

> "Note that `parse()` returns an `ElementTree` object, not an `Element` object as the string parser functions"

To get the equivalent type, you need to call `getroot()` :

```
.....
tree = etree.parse(StringIO("<test/>"), parser)
elem1 = tree.getroot()
elem2 = etree.fromstring("<test/>", parser)

print(isinstance(elem1, honk), type(elem1))
print(isinstance(elem2, honk), type(elem2))
```

**output :**

```
True <class '__main__.honk'>
True <class '__main__.honk'>
```